# Vimeo jQuery Event Call Back

Tags: jquery, callback, vimeo

I'm trying to get my Vimeo Embedded player to call a function when a video is done. I can't get the callback function to call....

```
$.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://vimeo.com/7100569') + '&width=513&height=287&callback=?', function(data) {
    $('#mediaplayerHolder').html(data.html);
    $('iframe').each(function() {
        $f(this).addEvent('ready', function(player_id) {
            $f(player_id).addEvent('finish', function() {
                alert("finish");    
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out... for anyone else with the same problem it was because of a couple things.

1) I didn't have

```
api=1
```

in the JSON string.

2) I needed an ID in the JSON string and the iframe.

I put it all in a function to call the videos:

```
function playVideo(ID,autoPlay,playNext) {
    $('#mediaplayerHolder').find("iframe").remove();

    $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://vimeo.com/' + ID) + '&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=' + autoPlay + '&width=513&height=287&api=1&player_id=mediaplayer&callback=?', function(data) {
        $(data.html).attr("ID","mediaplayer").appendTo('#mediaplayerHolder');

        var iframe = $("iframe")[0],
            player = $f(iframe);

        player.addEvent("ready", function() {
            player.addEvent("finish",function() {
                if (playNext) {
                    $(".occupied:not(#" + ID + "):first").find(".playBtn").click();
                    $("#" + ID).find(".removeBtn").click(); 
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
}
```